# Function which replaces every digit inside of a string with a random digit

Tags: c, string, pointers, random, dynamic-memory-allocation

First of all I want to thank everyone who has helped me on my last issue, it helped me a lot with understanding of how a C program runs in the background and what loops are used for what. Now I'm encountered with this task: write a function which replaces every digit in a given string (0, 1, 2,... 9) (ASCII values: 48, 49, 50,... 57) with another random digit. Every other type of data in a string needs to remain untact. The task also says that, in main(), I'm supposed to create a string capable of holding 50 elements and do dynamic memory allocation for 50 char type elements - full capability of memory handling, and in the end print out the result of the function.

This is what I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* switching(char s[]){

    int i;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++){
    
        if(s[i] > 57 || s[i] < 48){
        
            s[i] = (float)rand()/RAND_MAX * 9;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main(){

    char *string = (char *)malloc(50);
    fgets(string, 80, stdin);

    if(string == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    char *r;

    r = switching(string);
    printf("%s" , r);
    free(r);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is what my apparent error is (although there might be more of them but I'm not sure) when i run it in OnlineGDB:

```
               Input: 1234abcd
               Expected output: 5865abcd
               Actual output: 1234
```

So yeah, as last time, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance to anyone that tries to help.
Edit: replaced `"%c"` with `"%s` in `printf();` and addded `fgets(string, 80, stdin);` but it still doesnt completely work.

Comment: Well, `switching()` returns a `char *`, but the `%c` conversion specifier expects an `int` (which is what happens to a `char` after the integer promotions). If you want to print a string, use `%s`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void switching(char *s){

    int i=0;
    char tmp;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<49;i++){
        if(s[i] < 58 && s[i] > 47){
            tmp = (char)((rand()%9) + 48);
            if (s[i] != tmp)
                s[i]=tmp;
            else
                i--;
        }
    }
}
void generate(char *s){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    static const char alphanum[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(i=0; i<49; i++)
        s[i]=alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    s[i]='\0';
}


int main(){

    char *string = (char *)malloc(50);

    if(string == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    generate(string);
    printf("Source string:%s\n", string);
    switching(string);
    printf("Output string:%s\n" , string);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Source string:Tp1NJ1dmaC2V8NOld9gzt8pShf3K7UpYHrwaqXNQhPvnmHWNR
Output string:Tp4NJ6dmaC0V2NOld7gzt3pShf7K5UpYHrwaqXNQhPvnmHWNR
```